# how to manipulate mp3 songs and remove the vocal and leave only the background music?

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, music

I want to karaoke but my mp3 files hold vocal music.

I want to make music instrument because I want to karaoke

How can I manipulate mp3 songs and remove the vocal and leave only the background music?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I did not find that work

Comment: [Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html) can do it, but this operation has limitations. It strongely depends on mastering level of recorded mp3. With [unmastered music version](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/ue46WiOlZ4g) you have great chance to isolate voice track.

Comment: @Redbob - True, it is difficult to completely remove just vocals from a mp3. Audacity is mentioned in the answer I linked to as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, @bodhi.zazen, I saw. Audacity how-to reference at that answer was taken from howtogeek.com (that's how I do it, too), but as he said it didn't work, I showed that Audacity wiki page to suggest him to go deeper at this matter.

Comment: It is easier to download if you can. There are several services http://www.karasongs.com/ for example. Unless you have a recording with an isolated vocal track it is very difficult to remove vocals.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am confused with this problem but it is difficult to remove vocals